# Where does the drush installtation command set the PROMPT_COMMAND variable?

Tags: drush

I installed [drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) and as part of the installation it makes some changes to the command prompt.

```
...
# Optional. Enrich the bash startup file with completion and aliases.
drush init
...
```

Whenever I execute an command at the prompt I get the message:

```
bash: __drush_ps1: command not found
```

The `env` command displays `PROMPT_COMMAND` as

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=__git_ps1 "\u@\h \w" "$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]") \\\$ "
```

I think somewhere at the global level the PROMPT_COMMAND variable is set to that value but I can't locate it in any of the global environment variables and profile scripts.

Because `drush` was installed as `root` commands executed as `root` don't produce that error message. `root` has a `.drush` directory with some `drush` scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that changes the .bash_profile or .bashrc file is [`drush_init_core_init()`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/commands%21core%21init.drush.inc/function/drush_init_core_init/8.0.x). The shell script that effectively sets the prompt is `$home/.drush/drush.prompt.sh`, where `$home` is the value returned from [`drush_server_home()`](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/includes%21environment.inc/function/drush_server_home/8.0.x). If the file doesn't exist, `drush_init_core_init()` creates it from the content of `DRUSH_BASE_PATH . "/examples/example.prompt.sh"`, which contains the following line. (See [example.prompt.sh](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/examples%21example.prompt.sh/8.0.x).)

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h \w" "$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]") \\\$ "'
```

There is also the following line, which sets `PS1` and that is is commented out by default. (See the comment before it.)

```
  # PROMPT_COMMAND is used in the example above rather than PS1 because neither
  # Git nor Drush color hints are compatible with PS1. If you don't want color
  # hints, however, and prefer to use PS1, you can still do so by commenting out
  # the PROMPT_COMMAND line above and uncommenting the PS1 line below:
  #
  # export PS1='\u@\h \w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")$(__drush_ps1 "[%s]")\$ '
```

As for the error message you see, `__drush_ps1()` is a bash function used to change the prompt, defined in [drush.complete.sh](http://api.drush.org/api/drush/drush.complete.sh/8.0.x). [bash completion/prompt broken](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1799) explains exactly when and why you get that error. TLDR; in some circumstances, the shell script is not sourced, and the Bash function results not defined.
For what I understand it, the error has been has been fixed in recent versions, though, so you should just need to update Drush to fix the error.

Comment: The problem is I don't know which file sets the PROMPT_COMMAND in both the user's bash configuration filEs and in /etc/. I'd prefer to change it in there. None of the files in /etc/bash_completion.d contain any command to set PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: I will add that information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of simpler work-around to remove that error message - edit:

```
~/.drusysconfig/bash_prompt
```

i.e.

```
nano ~/.drusysconfig/bash_prompt
```

and remove row:

```
PS1="\[${BOLD}${MAGENTA}\]\u\[$WHITE\]@\[$ORANGE\]\h\[$WHITE\]:\[$GREEN\]\w \[$PURPLE\]\$(__git_ps1 '(%s)')\[$ORANGE\]\[$WHITE\]\n\$ \[$RESET\]"
```